# Visual Studio Django app fails to build with StaticRootPath error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing my first Django app, and I have encountered a problem. When I go to build the project in visual studio, the build fails without giving any errors. 
The only way I can get it to show me an error at all is by changing the output to diagnostic mode, at which point it shows me this:

```
Target "DetectStaticRootPath" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Python 
Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets" from project 
"C:\Users\OEM\Documents\TSM_shared\student-marketplace-v2\ecommerce 
test\ecommerce test.pyproj" (target "DjangoCollectStaticFiles" depends on it):
Initializing task factory "RunPythonCommandFactory" from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Microsoft.PythonTools.BuildTasks.dll".
Using "RunPythonCommand" task from the task factory "RunPythonCommandFactory".
Task "RunPythonCommand"
    Task Parameter:Target=import test.settings as settings; print(settings.STATIC_ROOT or '')
    Task Parameter:TargetType=code
    Task Parameter:ExecuteIn=none
    Task Parameter:WorkingDirectory=.
    Task Parameter:Environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=test.settings
    Task Parameter:ConsoleToMSBuild=True
    Output Property: DjangoStaticRootSetting=
Done executing task "RunPythonCommand" -- FAILED.
Done building target "DetectStaticRootPath" in project "test.pyproj" -- FAILED.
```

Those are the only parts of the build that fail.
Below is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'app',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You shouldn't use `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATICFILES_ROOT` together, I think this is the problem. Off documentations for working with static files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the problem. I have tried both individually, and the build will still fail. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: Have you tried to run a server from the command line?

Comment: yes, manage.py runserver works as usual, and everything loads as it should.

Comment: Did you add static to url patterns?

Comment: No, I haven't. Can you please tell me how I should go about doing that?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Ok, despite that, the error is still thrown when I build the project. As I said, when running a server, even with debug=false, there are no errors. Could this problem be related to something I didn't code myself?

Comment: No, I think it depends on MSVS